# Permanent search in header (w/ Bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

New to Bootstrap, but I want to have a header that always has a search bar on it regardless of the screen size.  The nav bar will always have the search box and button, and then depending on the screen size have a set of links/buttons that will collapse on smaller devices.  The search and the links should be on the same row.

Right now there seem to be issues with search box growing/shrinking and the links getting moved to a second row.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Project</a>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 pull-left">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Shows</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">States</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Road Trip</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">Shows</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">States</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Road Trip</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
```

This also bar disappears on a smaller resolution, is that intentional?